# Does the Display attribute in the model violate separation of concerns from view and model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Might be a stupid question.
But doesn't specifying the caption in the model using the Display attribute violate the separation of concerns principle?  Shouldn't the caption belong in the view?

If it does not, could somebody explain why it belongs in the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MVC framework allows you to put the `DataAnnotations` in a model, but strictly talking `DataAnnotations` should be placed in a ViewModel and not in a Model mapped to the database.

Comment: +1 - exactly where the DataAnnotations should be placed (viewModel)

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not violate the pattern if it is your **ViewModel**.

> A ViewModel is, usually, a simple POCO (Plain old CLR Object) that
>   contains no business logic, mostly only properties.

The `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyProperty)` method will look for the Display attribute
and use that information. So the right way is to use the attribute instead of any kind of hard coded text in your view.

**hope this helps**

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fine line between isolating your domain model from the view and having an anemic domain model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model). I personally think it's ok to expose your domain model in certain places as properties on the view model.

My personal peeve with an anemic domain model is namely the liability that it *"Facilitates code duplication among transactional scripts and similar use cases, reduces code reuse."*

Comment: Agree, I do the same most of the time.